# How to know image was translated or not with matrix?

Tags: android, matrix

I'm using TouchImageView from github and using matrix.posttranslate to handle user control of dragging zoom image. Problem is I need to know when user drag to border of image, so image can't move horizontally any more. Has anyone have ideal about that?

Comment: I am not familiar with GitHub or other projects, but I presume there is some sort of GestureListener method that receives a motionevent (you use it to create the matrix perhaps) .. you can easily add checks there.

Comment: Oh no, i don't use any gesturelistener, i use ontouchlistener for basic. And problem is params of matrix.posttranslate aren't related to how much image translate. When you swipe to border, image don't move anymore though you posttranlate...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not rotating your `Matrix` then second and fifth elements are `translateX` and `translateY`:

```
    final Matrix matrix = ...;
    final float[] values = new float[9];

    matrix.getValues(values);

    final float translateX = values[2];
    final float translateY = values[5];
```

Comment: I try logging two values you have mentioned above, and i can see how they changed. When i swipe to the left, translateX=0, right? But while i swipe to the right border of image, translateX = "constX", and "constX" changed depend on how i zoom image. So how can i know when swipe to right border?

Comment: Please help me, translateX/scale also is not const? I can't understand how translateX change when zoom image

Comment: no, it's not a constant. `translateX` changes depend on the pivot point that you pass to `Matrix.postScale`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. And after deeply read sourcecode of gallery on github, i got solution. To check whether swipe to right border or not:

```
float scaledWidth = Math.round(mOrigWidth * mSaveScale);
                    if (Math.abs(mViewWidth - translateX - scaledWidth) <= 1.0) {
                        // drag to right border
                        ALog.d("touchimageview", "right x: "
                                + (mViewWidth - translateX - scaledWidth));
                        touchEventListener.onZoomToOriginal();
                        break;
                    }
```